# Master node of galera cluster is not in sync, how should I sync them?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, clustering, galera

master node server id 10

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment';
+---------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name             | Value          |
+---------------------------+----------------+
| wsrep_local_state_comment | Donor/Desynced |
+---------------------------+----------------+
```

non primary server id 11

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment';
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| wsrep_local_state_comment | Synced |
+---------------------------+--------+
```

remote node, server id 20

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment';
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| wsrep_local_state_comment | Synced |
+---------------------------+--------+
```

but I also checked if these nodes have diverged,

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_last_committed';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+----------------------+----+
| wsrep_last_committed | 8 |
+----------------------+----+
```

all these 3 nodes returns the same value .

so I would presume they have not diverged but primary node  is not in sync ? what does that mean ?

how can I fix this currently I get this error:

```
ERROR 1047 (08S01): WSREP has not yet prepared node for application us
```

I added `wsrep_sst_donor=192.168.5.12` # this non primary node server id 11.
in the dsynced master node my.cnf

but master still shows:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wsrep_sst_donor';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| wsrep_sst_donor |       |
+-----------------+-------+
```

very scared if sudo systemctl restart mariadb would be safe !

Answer (score 1):

Galera does not have a master node, only a collection of servers identified as primary.

Check all servers have the same galera UUID of the server.  Work out which server data is most up to date. This should be the donor. Do get two running on the same UUID before restarting another.

You can copy the datadir of a shutdown mariadb instance as a backup.

See [Recovering Primary Component](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/pc-recovery.html) in the documentation - https://dba.stackexchange.com/u/158002